# Ionic - How to do a matrix like checkbox

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

How do I display multiple checkbox to display like this?

```
          Col1    Col2    Col3
Row 1     []      []       []
Row 2     []      []       []
```

```
<div *ngFor="let row of item.rows">
  <ion-item>
    <div *ngFor="let col of item.columns">
      <ion-label>{{row}}</ion-label>
      <ion-label>{{col}}</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox [id]="item.id"></ion-checkbox>
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us how item loooks like?

Comment: the item comes from a query in database that is an object it looks something like this
{
    columns:["col 1,col2, col3"]
    title: "some title"
    rows:["row1, row2]
    id: 1
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row *ngFor="let rows of matrix.row; let i=index ">
    <ion-label>
      {{rows}}
    </ion-label>
    <ion-col *ngFor="let cols of matrix.column">
    <ion-label *ngIf="i==0">{{cols}}</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox [id]="matrix.id"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Component File:

```
matrix:any={
        column :['col1','col2','col3'],
        row : ['row1','row2'],
        title: 'test',
        id:1
    }
```

Comment: it works but I have one issue though, the first row label is inlined with the label of the columns not with the first row of the checkbox